# How to invoke a flow/trigger if a user fails login attempt?

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, security, login, loginflow

**What Needs to Happen**: When a user logs into the org, we perceive the attempt as either Successful (correct password), Failed (incorrect password), or Other. If the user fails the login attempt, a User object field 'Failed Attempt Counter' is increased by 1. Once the counter reaches 3, an email is sent.

**The Problem**: The process above has been created using a Flow/Process Builder, however, since Login Flows are only invoked post-authentication, the Flow only every updates when their is a Successful login attempt. I can call the Flow I've created if I can find a way to invoke it every time a User attempts to log in, but I can't call LoginHistory from a trigger, and the Flow won't start until their is a Successful login attempt.

**Question**: How do I invoke Apex/Flow/Process Builder Flow whenever someone logs in? Is there a better solution?

The Flow in case you are interested (though not necessary to answer my question): 
[image: Flow]

Comment: is it password reset mail you send when that counter reaches 3?

Comment: @Pranay, it is not. The email is sent to Security to alert them of the numerous failed attempts.

Comment: if you know we can lock user after some password attempts.. we can also configure that except admin none can unlock the usert

Comment: @pranay, if I'm understanding you correctly, you are saying we should look at the locked user field that is updated on LoginHistory object when a user is locked out and trigger the event from there. Unfortunately, you can't call from Apex.

Comment: @PranayJaiswal and you cannot invoke a flow unless you use Process Builder and Process Builder doesn't have access to the Login History object...

Comment: Let me answer it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot run a process builder/trigger/workflow without logging in.

The best you do is with invalid password then lockout the user. Set the lockout effective period to forever, then show a locked user a page asking them to email the admin/security team. By this way, the security team will always know whats going on with users.

[image]

---

**Another Approach** will be to schedule a Scheduler every 30mins to 1 hour.

The scheduler will query LoginHistory table for LoginTime=Today

```
SELECT ApiType,ApiVersion,Application,AuthenticationServiceId,Browser,CipherSuite,ClientVersion,CountryIso,Id,LoginGeoId,LoginTime,LoginType,LoginUrl,NetworkId,Platform,SourceIp,Status,TlsProtocol,UserId FROM LoginHistory where LoginTime=Today
```

Then iterate over the records to find a record where status='Invalid Password' (You cannot use status field as filter on query for LoginHistory)

Once found gather it, make a set and then send an aggegate email to the System's team

Comment: Thanks for the information. I'm aware of this option, but it is not a solution. Here Salesforce provides some information on handling login exceptions and make it seem that what I'm talking about is possibe, but there is little detail on triggering this and where: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000212767&type=1

Comment: @paulK i have updated my answer to include use of Login History Scheduler.

Comment: Ok that is an interesting idea. I know they have scheduler limits that are 250k so this might work. However, it does seem like just running code for no reason. Not very efficient. Crazy there isn't a solution for this from Salesforce.

Comment: I understand the overhead, but it's not to bad if you run it every 15 mins.. it will only take 96 Daily Async Jobs out of 250,000, which doesn't look like a big number. With limited SF featured one has to resort to this polling architecture.

Comment: Ok. I'm going to meet with a couple other experts today about this. If no better solution, I'll mark yours as the best. Thanks again, Pranay!

Comment: Hey @paulK did the experts provided you any solution, am curious about it.

Comment: Hey @Pranay I haven't forgotten about you. Expecting to hear back this week. Will update when I have an answer from their team.

Comment: haven't heard back from our guys yet. Went ahead and just made it the best solution.